# Converting hash table to JSON with '\'

Tags: json, powershell

I am familiar with how to convert hash tables to JSON and posting using invoke-RestMethod...

Though I'm running into this challenging issue. 'Identites' in the below code represents an AD Group.

```
    $body = @{
            Name =  $group
            Description =  $group
            Identities = "[thedemodrive\group1]"
        }
$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

The JSON return comes back with an extra \ which is not accepted by the endpoint

```
{
    "Identities":  "[thedemodrive\\group1]",
    "Description":  "group1",
    "Name":  "group1"
}
```

Why is this happening and how do I go around it? How do I keep a single `\` in the JSON return?

Comment: It's happening because it's supposed to -- backslashes need to be escaped in JSON strings, otherwise ``\g`` would be an escape sequence. If the endpoint complains, it shouldn't be about the backslash.

Comment: “Not accepted” does not help us help you. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$body = @{
    Name =  $group
    Description =  $group
    Identities = "[thedemodrive\group1]"
}
$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json | % { [regex]::Unescape($_) }
```

Comment: Did you find the Answer?